# XSLT Code Inside ASPX Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

I have `xslt` document  which I included inside `xml` file(the file below). I have `aspx` page and I want to include this xml file inside this `aspx` page and when I run `aspx` page the `xslt` code in `xml` to run too. Is it possible ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="simpletransform.xslt"?>
<JavacoTea>
   Try our new Herbal Tea!
</JavacoTea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ASP.NET WebForms there used to be a control to perform XSLT within a page, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35b30hy4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx. Note however that that control uses `System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform` to perform the XSLT transformation, an implementation of XSLT 1.0 done by Microsoft in the .NET versions 1.x while later .NET versions have `System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform`.

And if you want the browser to perform the XSLT transformation (as your posted code does) then I would suggest to simply include an `iframe` element in your code e.g.  `<iframe with="100%" height="200" src="yourXmlFile.xml"></iframe>`.

Comment: I found XML Control     <asp:Xml ID="Xml1" runat="server" DocumentSource="~/PlanetCafe.xml"
                TransformSource="~/PlanetCafe.xslt"></asp:Xml>. This works for reading xslt from xml and transform it to aspx page.